# Different durations for CSS properties in jQuery animate()

Tags: jquery, animation

I’m using jQuery to animate DOM element on the page and I hit an obstacle when using its native `animate()`.

I’m trying to move my element to the right and change its opacity.

```
$element.animate({
    'left': '50%',
    'opacity': '1.0'
}, 1000);
```

It works very well, but I need to animate **position** in `1000`ms and **opacity** in `300`ms.

I found out that **I can’t** write it like this:

```
$element.animate({
    'left': '50%'
}, 1000);


$element.animate({
    'opacity': '1.0'
}, 300);
```

This will result in queued animation, because it is the same element and jQuery apparently needs to wait for the first animation to finish. Or I’m doing something wrong here.

I tried using second argument notation (based on http://api.jquery.com/animate) and using `queue: false` but it didn’t work. I must say I don’t understand it thoroughly, so any corrections are welcome.

So my question is this – how to independently change duration interval for these CSS properties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you were on the right track when trying to use `queue`. Here's an example of how this should be working, I hope it helps :

```
$('#element').animate({ left:'50%' }, { queue: false, duration: 1000 })
             .animate({ opacity : '1.0' }, { queue : false, duration: 300 });
```

**Edit:** Successfully Tested :)

Comment: Thanks, this is it. It doesn’t just work for my code, but I must have some conflicting calls – vanilla demo works, so this is the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Could you animate both in one call for 300 ms. up to 3/10 of the position change, and then animate the remainder of the position change for another 700ms?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I might do it, if anything else fails. It’s not exactly a nice way to code :)